# Choosing a multiclass strategy

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, multi-class

What would be the best approach to choosing the multi-class strategy (MSVM, OVA, ECOC) for classifying a large number of classes with limited examples of each class?

Another two factors that define the solution, in my case:

- The probability of prediction is an important factor that decides the next steps in my solution.
- The size (i.e. size of the classifier object on disk which can later be loaded in memory and used for prediction), of the fitted classifier (since I need the solution to be portable without providing it as a service). I do not need to analyze the classifier(s) any more than getting the category with reasonable probability.

  UPDATE: The problem is basically that of text classification.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on what you mean by the "size" of the classifier i.e. disk storage or complexity or what ?

Comment: Size as in disk storage...as of now I am trying to get the answers without limiting the features and accuracy.